# Mobile browser add background to m svg

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image

I am using this svg as background of input type="range" thump via background-image

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="3.33691" y="3.37695" width="3.33612" height="3.37622" fill="#695B51"/>
<rect x="3.33691" y="16.8809" width="3.33612" height="3.37622" fill="#695B51"/>
<rect x="16.6826" y="3.37695" width="3.33612" height="3.37622" fill="#695B51"/>
<rect x="16.6826" y="16.8809" width="3.33612" height="3.37622" fill="#695B51"/>
<rect width="10.0084" height="23.6334" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 16.6826 0)" fill="#695B51"/>
<rect width="10.0084" height="16.881" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 16.6826 3.37695)" fill="#F0BA15"/>
<rect y="6.75195" width="23.3528" height="10.1287" fill="#695B51"/>
<rect x="3.33691" y="6.75195" width="16.6806" height="10.1287" fill="#F0BA15"/>
</svg>
```

here is my css

```
.sliderBar::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url('../../public/sliderthump.svg');
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
```

Every thing seems to be fine until i see that in mobile version it auto add white background to my image,

this is desktop version
[image]

and this is mobile version
[image]

How can i remove the white background in this case or do we have any alternative?

Comment: On which mobile browsers showing white background. I just checking on mobile chrome browser so its working fine without white background.

Comment: i check on Chorme and safari on iphone xsmax

Comment: Got it so you just need replace **background-image** to **background: url(...)** then white background will remove.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace **`background-image: url(...)`** to **`background: url(...)`** then white background will remove.

```css
body{
    background-color: #f9bcbc;
    padding: 20px;
}
.sliderBar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 75%;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fbe87b;
    outline: none;
}
.sliderBar[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect x='3.33691' y='3.37695' width='3.33612' height='3.37622' fill='%23695B51'/><rect x='3.33691' y='16.8809' width='3.33612' height='3.37622' fill='%23695B51'/><rect x='16.6826' y='3.37695' width='3.33612' height='3.37622' fill='%23695B51'/><rect x='16.6826' y='16.8809' width='3.33612' height='3.37622' fill='%23695B51'/><rect width='10.0084' height='23.6334' transform='matrix(-1 0 0 1 16.6826 0)' fill='%23695B51'/><rect width='10.0084' height='16.881' transform='matrix(-1 0 0 1 16.6826 3.37695)' fill='%23F0BA15'/><rect y='6.75195' width='23.3528' height='10.1287' fill='%23695B51'/><rect x='3.33691' y='6.75195' width='16.6806' height='10.1287' fill='%23F0BA15'/></svg>");
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="sliderBar" value="10">
```

Comment: It's not work, you can check it by using chorme mobile

Comment: I was checked in Safari. It's working but now let me check in chrome also...

Comment: Now I just check in both browsers Safari and Chrome it's working fine on iPhone 6s.

Comment: don't know why but my iphone 7plus and xs max always show the background